# c++ using class to count lines in file

Tags: c++, class

I am trying to move my line counting function into a class, however, I am getting a few errors, and I have no idea how to make it work.

```
    class lines {
        string name;
        int number_of_lines;
        string line;
    public:
        void set_value (string n);
        ifstream myfile(name);   //C2061: syntax error : identifier 'name'
        while (getline(myfile, line))  //Multiple markers at this line - C2059: syntax error : 'while', - Syntax error
        {                         // C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
            ++number_of_lines;
        }
        int row() {return number_of_lines;}
    };

 void lines::set_value (string n) {
 number_of_lines=0;
     name = n;
 }
```

I added the errors as comments to the rows they show up on.

Comment: That's got a lot of problems.

First off, you're using variable names rather than types in function declarations. Secondly, you're declaring member functions and then doing a block of code which I assume you're intending as the member function definition in the class definition.

Comment: Keep it simple. Read byte by byte into two-byte buffer using buffered input and check for CR/LF/CRLF sequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change code

```
        string line;
public:
        void set_value (string n);
        ifstream myfile(name);   //C2061: syntax error : identifier 'name'
        while (getline(myfile, line))  //Multiple markers at this line - C2059: syntax error : 'while', - Syntax error
        {                         // C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
            ++number_of_lines;
        }
```

to :

```
public:
    void set_value (string name)
    {
        ifstream myfile(name);
        string line;
        while (getline(myfile, line)) 
        {               
            ++number_of_lines;
        }
        myfile.close();
    }
```

Comment: This seems to have fixed the while and name errors, but gives a bunch of syntax errors at the first "{" bracket: - Syntax error
 - C2059: syntax error : '{'
 - C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever operation/calculation you are doing in C++ that must be inside some function, here you are using the below statements inside class that must be inside some function.

```
ifstream myfile(name);   //C2061: syntax error : identifier 'name'
        while (getline(myfile, line))  //Multiple markers at this line - C2059: syntax error : 'while', - Syntax error
        {                         // C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
            ++number_of_lines;
        }
```